# Select Project Type to build by Visual Studio Configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

In my Visual Studio Project we are using 2 Different Membership Providers we would like by build configuration type to have the selected project added to the Web Project

- MyApplication.Provider   - **DEBUG** - (SQL Membership Provider)
- MyApplication.Provider.AD - **RELEASE** - (AD Membership Provider)
- MyApplication.Web (ASP.NET MVC Project)

When we are debugging locally on our machine I want the project to use project reference for the **MyApplication.Provider**  and when creating a release project I want to load the **MyApplication.Provider.AD**

In both projects I made the public classes use the matching namespaces.
In the build configuration for each configuration I excluded the Project not utilized

For the Web.config differences in the Post Build Option I can successfully add the correct Web.config File.

The Issue is that when I build the solution I cannot get the correct project DLL added to the Web Project.

What is the Best practice way to handle this, Do I need to modify the web project .csproj with a MSBuild Command  or are there other project settings I need to configure to handle this.

Comment: Why don't you use web.config transformations?

Comment: Found the Solution that many before have stated http://sedodream.com/CommentView,guid,68b7e248-b9f5-4d07-bdfe-eb037bcf2cbb.aspx